# Sorting an arraylist of a class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

```
public class Giocatore {
private String nome;
private int punteggio;

public Giocatore(String nome, int punteggio) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.punteggio = punteggio;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public int getPunteggio() {
    return punteggio;
}

public void setPunteggio(int punteggio) {
    this.punteggio = punteggio;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Giocatori [nome=" + nome + ", punteggio=" + punteggio + "]";
}
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class CreazioneSquadre {

private ArrayList<Giocatore> giocatori;
private String [] squadraA;
private String [] squadraB;

public CreazioneSquadre() {
    giocatori = new ArrayList<Giocatore>();
    squadraA = new String[5];
    squadraB = new String[5];
}

public void creazioneGiocatori() {
    Random random = new Random();
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore1" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore2" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore3" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore4" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore5" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore6" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore7" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore8" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore9" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
    giocatori.add(new Giocatore("Giocatore10" , random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
}

public void SortGiocatori() {

    
}


public void stampa() {
    for (int i = 0; i < giocatori.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1) + ") Nome: " + giocatori.get(i).getNome() + " Punteggio: " + giocatori.get(i).getPunteggio());
    }
}   
}
```

hi guys, i'trying to make a program that make for me a football team, this is the first version that i would improve. Where is the problem? I would sort the ArrayList giocatori, but is an ArrayList of a class, so i have a problem when i use Collections.sort(), how could i do for sort it? and... do u habe any suggestion for make this program better? it's just a stupid project im working because every week i go to play football with my friends and i thought why not create a program that make for us the teams. For improve it id like to put the value of "puneggio" for the skills and with it choose where team that player will go, bur for now is enought if it choose it randomly

Comment: Write an implementation of interface [java.util.Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or make class `Giocatore` implement interface [java.lang.Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You can specify your own comparator without having to actually implement the comparable interface.

- first argument - the list to be sorted.
- second argument - the comparator specifying the field of the `Giocatore` class on which to sort.

```
public void SortGiocatori() {
    Collections.sort(giocatori, Comparator.comparing(Giocatore::getPunteggio));
}
```

Comment: thank u, it solved my problem :)